# Javascript Opening hours countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I would like to use an opening time countdown for individual days on my website for a local shop. The shop has opening hours from monday to friday from 09:00 to 18:00 and is open on saturdays from 10:00 to 16:30.
I would like to show the users how long the store is open for the day they visit the website. For example a user is on the site on tuesday at 16:30 I want to display something like "Dear customer, our shop is open for another 1,5  hrs.".
If the shop is already closed, I would like to display something like "We are currently closed, but you are welcome to visit the store on Monday at 9 o'clock.".

I did a lot of research here and elsewhere, but i just couldn't find a proper solution for this task, so I really hope you could help me.

Comment: You did a lot of research? [Here](http://countdownjs.org/). Found after 2 sec.

Comment: Have you considered hiring a programmer? We're happy to help you solve a problem with your code, not code an application for you, for free. If you've tried something and want help, please show us the code you've tried and what problems you are having with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array mapping your Openning time, with 0 is Sunday

```
var openTime = [ {open : -1, close : -1},
                 { open: 9, close : 18 },
                 { open: 9, close : 18 },
                 { open: 9, close : 18 },
                 { open: 9, close : 18 }, 
                 { open: 9, close : 18 },
                 { open: 10, close : 16.5 }
              ]
```

then check it when user come to page.

```
var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var currentTime = current.getHours() + (current.getMinutes()/60);
var remainTime = 0;
if (openTime[day].open >= 0 && openTime[day].open < currentTime && openTime[day].close > currentTime) {
         remainTime= (openTime[day].close  - currentTime).toFixed(2)
}
console.log("the shop will close in %s hours", remainTime);
```

Comment: fix logic open ,close

Comment: This is looking very good. How can I sho wthe time inside a certain div? I tried [something here](http://jsfiddle.net/hupnaybv/), but it looks like there are some mistakes Also, how can I add another message when the shop is closed?

Comment: it seems you didn't know the basic of programmer, it's ok if you're not a programmer, but terrible but yes. Fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/hupnaybv/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just learning and I still often get confused with some code. Can you help me how I can display a different message for when the shop is closed?

Comment: you see the `if`-statement I put on it? If it jump into `if` that mean your shop is openning. So, think about `else`-statement and fix it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to get the current Date and then get the Day of week, You can do it like that:

```
var currentdate = new Date();

// this will return a number between 0 and 6 indicating the day of the week.
// starting with 0 for Sunday.
var dayofweek = currentdate.getDay();
```

And than depending on the day of the week you can calculate the remaining time similar to that:

```
//e.g Friday:
if(dayofweek==5)
{
    var closedate=new Date();
    closedate.setMinutes(0);
    closedate.setHours(18);

    // this will give you the difference between the current time and opening time.
    var diff = closedate.getTime()-currentdate.getTime();
    var diff_seconds = diff / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to keep track of opening hours based on the day of the week, you will have to get a handle on the current [date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) first like others have pointed out. You could do something like this:

```
 var d = new Date();
 d.getDay(); //returns the day of the week. Monday is 1 and so on.
```

Once you have the day of the week, it's just a matter of getting the current time using:

```
 d.getHours();
 d.getMinutes();
 d.getSeconds();
```

Once you have the time in this form. You can easily calculate how much time is left for the store to close based on your constraints. Hope this gets you started in the right direction.